# Indeterminate progress bar not becoming invisible

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is the code that instantiate a window with an indeterminate progress bar:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
progressbar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.ProgressBar_pm);
progressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
somefunc();
```

and here is how somefunc() looks like:

```
void somefunc()
{
  progressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
  /* Here is some time consuming code*/
  progressbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible
}
```

The progress bar is visible but it does not became invisible and it became visible after that time consuming process is through. There are some edittext and toast in that time consuming code too.

Comment: 1) is `somefunc` running on the UI thread? 2) `some time consuming code` is this code running on the UI thread?

Comment: @SushiHangover yes everything  is running on the same thread because there are some editbox and some other thing in there .

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by running the time consuming code on another thread and UI stuff on the main one.